# Git fetch returns same result if ran sequentially

Tags: git, powershell, version-control

I was wondering if there was a way to suppress a git fetch that doesn't get any objects instead of it spitting out the list of new branches/objects from the previous fetch eg:

```
C:/git> git fetch
remote: Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server
remote: Found 4522 objects to send. (3362 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (4522/4522), 6.92 MiB | 3.46 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3477/3477), completed with 1258 local objects.
From remote
*[new branch] abc
*[new branch] def
*[new branch] ghi
*[new branch] jkl

C:/git> git fetch
*[new branch] abc
*[new branch] def
*[new branch] ghi
*[new branch] jkl
```

Basically on the second git fetch I want to suppress the output as those branches aren't really new - this persists even after pulling , even tried the `--all` switch, the fact it doesn't say receiving new objects seems to me like it knows they're old, but still shows me. Any ideas?

Comment: @tim yes thats exactly it, any git fetch will still present these branches even after a pull

Comment: git fetch does not present any output if the fetch doesn't retrieve any objects. Which version of git are you using?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous it seems that the issue is if you have branches with different casing in it, it will only take note of the branches it recognises in that casing eg: feature/bugfix will go into a refs folder with 'feature' but not 'Feature' and the same thing for a branch with Feature/bugfix2 wont go into a ref folder 'feature' only 'Feature' .. this doesnt seem to get fixed by ignoring case with git config..